# IMAP in ASP.Net C #

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to download email by IMAP service from a gmail account through code in C# ASP>Net. I have no sound about it and new to development in this plate form. Please guide me and help me about it. Any link or reference???

Answer (score 2):

You need to use third-party components witch are available in different kind and prices, or you can develop it your own with socket programming. 
take a look at :

- http://www.limilabs.com/mail
- http://www.afterlogic.com/

you also need to enable IMAP on your Gmail account so you can send and receive with IMAP Protocol in your application.  For sending emails you also need SMTP configuration to be set.

- http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77695

also take a look at webmail scripts developed by asp.net, it would be a great guide!
Google's Gmail API Reffrence is also a good guide, if you want to use API instead of starting by nothing. take a look at :

- https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/